Trying to determine appropriate dosage for rose systemic treatment
I purchased BioAdvanced All in one Rose and Flower Care Concentrate.  (Systemic/drench)
The instructions state

Roses: 2 fl.oz in 1 quart of water treats 1 plant.

I have hybrid tea roses that are 1' tall x 1' wide and English roses that are 6' tall and 6' wide.
For other shrubs they state to use 1 fl oz to 1 quart of water per foot of plant height.
I am fairly sure that 1 quart of diluted mix will not adequately treat the largest rose bush, but I also don't want to use too much and harm the plants.
Anyone have knowledge on how much is appropriate based on size of a rose bush?

Just an FYI - I did get a response from the company which states that they don't recommend using the product on miniature roses as it can burn the rose and they don't recommend using on climbing roses because they don't absorb the product the same as other rose bushes.    This is telling me that the dosage is different for different size roses.  They just won't qualify the statement by providing the size of the roses where this ratio/quantity is effective.

It's really interesting that the company hides the ingredients for this priduct. According to a rather blurry photo that I found, the insectide is imidicloprid. This is a neonictinoid and will kill all pollinating insects that visit the roses.
If you value your local environment, return this to the place where you bought it. Using a systemic to kill Japanese beetles is completely ineffective, because the first thing the beetles do when they erupt from your lawn is mate and lay eggs.

I had a look at the BioAdvanced Sie, but they dont disclose the ingredients, instructions or cautions.
Amazon listing has instructions. I would follow the instructions.  Note, it is systemic, and supposed to be sucked up from the roots. So, it may well be enough. Otherwise you can repeat in 6 weeks.
On the other hand it sounds too good to be true. One take on that would be that the chemicals are dangerous. So, that's another reason to follow the instructions.
